# Получение value из form в php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form, php7

у меня есть вопрос по php:
как мне получить значения value у input из form, если form ещё не отправлена, как это сделать?
Или подскажите как это сделать так что-бы при клике на input в php отправлялся лишь значение value у input? А также если это возможно, то как получить данные в этом же файле без отправки в другой?

Comment: Что именно должно получить значение?

Comment: Используйте `ajax`  и вешайте ивент на инпут.

Comment: Значение должно перейти в переменную

Comment: Serghei Leonenco а как это сделать можете помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом коде создается переменная $message и в нее вносится значение input. Если вы хотите сохранить значение переменной после повторного открытия страницы, можно создать сессию (использовать cookie).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить" />
  </form>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST["message"])){$message = $_POST["message"]; echo $message;}
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```